# Problems passing tensor to linear layer - Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to build a neural net however I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the max pooling layer.

```
    self.embed1 = nn.Embedding(256, 8)
    self.conv_1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, (7,8), padding = (0,0))
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64, 2)

def forward(self,x):

    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    x = self.embed1(x) #input a tensor of ([1,217]) output size: ([1, 217, 8]) 
    x = x.unsqueeze(0) #conv lay needs a tensor of size (B x C x W x H) so unsqueeze here to make ([1, 1, 217, 8])
    x = self.conv_1(x) #creates 64 filter of size (7, 8).Outputs ([1, 64, 211, 1]) as 6 values lost due to not padding. 

    x = torch.max(x,0) #returning max over the 64 columns. This returns a tuple of length 2 with 64 values in each att, the max val and indices.
    x = x[0] #I only need the max values. This returns a tensor of size ([64, 211, 1])
    x = x.squeeze(2) #linear layer only wants the number of inputs and number of outputs so I squeeze the tensor to ([64, 211])
    x = self.fc1(x) #Error Size mismatch (M1: [64 x 211] M2: [64 x 2])
```

I understand why the linear layer isn't accepting 211 however I don't understand why my tensor after maxing over the columns isn't 64 x 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use of [`torch.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torch.html#torch.max) returns *two* outputs: the max value along dim=0 and the *argmax* along that dimension. Thus, you need to pick only the first output. (you might want to consider using [adaptive max pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d) for this task).

Your linear layer expects its input to have dim 64 (that is `batch_size`-by-`64` shaped tensor). However, it seems like your `x[0]` is of shape `13504`x`1` - definitely not 64.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53500838/1714410) for example.

Comment: Hi, so the size of x before being passed to fc1 is [64, 211, 1] I know I can squeeze it to 2 dimension but obviously [64, 211] isn't what I need either. I'm making a mistake somewhere but not sure what it is.

Comment: @Hughes_J look at [`.view()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) how to make tensor "look" differently

Comment: @Hughes_J your `torch.max(x, 0)` does not make sense to me: the batch dimension in your example is 1 you are taking a `max` of a number with itself. Are you sure you want to take the `max` over `dim=0` and not `dim=-2`?

Comment: Ok so this works, I'm going spend some time to understand why, but for now, a massive thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing your intentions correctly, your mistake is that you're using [`torch.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.max) for 2d maxpooling, instead of [`torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d). The former reduces across a tensor dimension (for instance across *all* feature maps or *all* horizontal lines), whereas the latter reduces in each square spatial neighborhood in the `[h, w]` plane of a `[batch, features, h, w]` tensor.

Comment: So if I want to reduce horizontal lines across x,I use F.max_pool2d(x,2)? Tried this and I'm still getting a tensor of size [1,64, 211, 1].

Comment: No, if you want to reduce horizontal lines use `torch.max(x, dim=3)` (and you get a 3d tensor output). `F.max_pool2d(x, 2)` will give you a 4d tensor where each `h, w` point contains the maximum of `[(h, w), (h+1, w), (h, w+1), (h+1, w+1)]`. If you're still confused, you perhaps need to write in your original questions more precisely what operations you want to do and which intermediate shapes you expect

Comment: You wrote what results and shapes you're obtaining, but my question was what you're _expecting_ to get. My problem is not that I can't work out how your code behaves, but that I don't know how you _want_ it to work.

That being said, `torch.max(x, 0)` is not "max over 64 columns", it's max over a singleton dimension. So `x = torch.max(x, 0); x = x[0]` could be replaced with just `x = x[0]`. I'm almost sure this is not what you want to do, but perhaps not your only error. If you want the maximum across the 64 elements, use `x = torch.max(x, 1); x = x[0]`

Comment: What do you mean by "column" for a 4 tensor? I can tell you to replace `x = self.fc1(x)` with `x = self.fc1(x.t())` (transposition of x) and it will stop raising exceptions, but I just don't believe this is what you want it to do. And I still don't understand what you want to do, the big picture, maybe in your own words.

Comment: Basically my train, data and val sets have two classes of items and I want to the net to learn to identify which each value belongs to. I'm sorry I can't explain it more but I'm very new to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
  x = x.squeeze(2)
```

You can do this instead:

```
  x = x.view(-1, 64) # view will now correctly resize it to [64 x 2]
```

You can think of view as numpy reshape. We use -1 to signify that we don't know how many rows we want but we know how many columns we have, 64.